# Pull and push image to ECR

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, docker-in-docker

How can I push a prebuild image from Docker hub (or another ECR) repository to my fresh ECR repository, pushing from within an unprivileged Fargate container on ECS?

**Why:**

I set up Amazon ECS and scaffold the setup using a standard image I currently host in Docker hub. All the setup is done with Terraform which also pulls and pushes the image from Docker hub to ECR so the ECS service can start pulling the image.

```
Terraform - Setup ECR
          <- Pull image from DockerHub
          -> Push image to ECR
          - Setup ECS (service and task definition)
```

Now I want to move the Terraform run from my local macOS to a pipeline which runs on ECS as a container. As I make use of the `kreuzwerker/docker` provider, I depend on the docker runtime. Sadly, Fargate ECS does not support Docker in Docker, and I'm kind of stuck how to "setup" ECR with my prebuild image.

Any help would be appreciated.

**What I considered so far:**

- skopeo - maybe the ultimate solution, but has no native Terraform support
- kaniko - potentially a solution, but I would need a lot of work to set it up inside my pipeline and do not know how to embed it into Terraform
- aws ecr CLI - does not support pull and push commands
- Docker in Docker - is not supported by Fargate as it does not allow privileged containers
- sysbox - requires change of runtime and also not supported in Fargate

Comment: Thank you for your question. Questions focused specifically on Docker, such as managing Docker in production, may be better answered by the experts in either the [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/). These platforms are highly knowledgeable in Docker and can provide comprehensive support tailored to your needs. As a reminder, all questions on Stack Overflow must be specifically related to programming. We appreciate your understanding and encourage you to visit the "on-topic" pages of either site before posting there to ensure a more relevant and helpful response.

Comment: You might find the regclient/regsync tool useful for this. It can run as a container with no privileges. Full disclosure: I'm the author.

Comment: Why are you trying to run a pipeline like this on ECS?  The unprivileged containers on Fargate aren't going to work here. AWS CodeBuild/CodePipeline is a purpose-built service on AWS for doing this sort of thing.

Comment: @Turing85 thanks for pointing this out. It's getting harder and harder to find the right stack.

Comment: @Mark B I use Gitlab and already have Gitlab runners on ECS and It's fun to use something which may also run on bare-metal Kubernetes instead of adding another service to the mix :)